# What is a git boundary commit

Tags: git

The [`git log` command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) has a `--boundary` option, which causes the program to

> Output excluded boundary commits.

But what is a *boundary commit*? And when might I want to include them in the output?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A boundary commit is the commit that limits a revision range but does not belong to that range. For example the revision range `HEAD~3..HEAD` consists of 3 commits (`HEAD~2`, `HEAD~1`, and `HEAD`), and the commit `HEAD~3` serves as a boundary commit for it.

More formally, git processes a revision range by starting at the specified commit and getting at other commits through the parent links. It stops at  commits that don't meet the selection criteria (and therefore should be excluded) - those are the boundary commits.

Illustration:

```
$ mkdir test
$ cd test
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in ~/playground/git/test/.git/
$ touch a
$ git add a
$ for i in {1..5}; do echo $i >> a; git commit -m "Commit #$i" a; done
[master (root-commit) bf958f1] Commit #1
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 a
[master 3721a8b] Commit #2
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
[master d69efcc] Commit #3
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
[master 72cd21d] Commit #4
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
[master 17ae9c3] Commit #5
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
$ git log --oneline
17ae9c3 Commit #5
72cd21d Commit #4
d69efcc Commit #3
3721a8b Commit #2
bf958f1 Commit #1
$ git log --oneline HEAD~3..
17ae9c3 Commit #5
72cd21d Commit #4
d69efcc Commit #3
$ git log --oneline HEAD~3.. --boundary
17ae9c3 Commit #5
72cd21d Commit #4
d69efcc Commit #3
- 3721a8b Commit #2     <-- This is the boundary commit HEAD~3 that would
                            not be included in the output had the '--boundary'
                            option NOT been provided
```

Comment: Interestingly, when doing a complex revision walk such as `br1...br2` to take all commits on either branch but not on both, you might expect the boundary commits to be limited to the merge bases, but they're not: you can get "stray" non-merge-base boundaries where the two depth-first walks "collided". I don't think one should count on this, as the graph walking algorithms may be changed at any time to improve speed, and that might create more or fewer boundaries. For simple exclusions (`reject..include`) there is only ever one boundary, fortunately.

Comment: good explanation. It is worth mentioning that, as said by [@CodeWizard in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42437808/86072), "boundary commits" can appear from a number of filtering criteria : `--since`, `--[no-]merges`, `--first-parent` and a number of other ones -- the notion is not limited to "the boundaries of one single range of commits `a..b`"

Answer (score 4):

> #### `--boundary`
>
> `--boundary`argument is to show context of commit(parent revision).

**A boundary commit is a commit that does not fall into the "frame" on which a command is executed. (--since, commit range etc)**

For example, if you use a parameter like `–since=3.weeks`, the commits **before three weeks** are considered as **`boundary commits`**. Usually `boundary` commits are marked with `-`

[image]

You can see in the above screenshot that the last commit is "gone" in the second log. Its due to the `--boundary` flag

You can see that there is a `o` sign before the commit instead of the `*` as in regular commits.

Answer (score 1):

I have a concrete example of when I want to see a boundary commit :

one way to compare the commits in two different branches is to look at the symmetric differences of two branches :

```
# for example: see the commits of a branch with respect to the commits in its upstream:
git log --graph --oneline <branch>...<branch>@{u}
```

One issue with the above command is : since the "symmetric differences" does not include the common base between the two branches, the output is a linear sequence of commits:

```
* (branch) local commit 3
* local commit 2
* local commit 1
* (origin/branch) remote commit 2
* remote commit 1
```

One better (imho) view is to draw the same graph while including the common merge base. This can be done by adding `--boundary` :

```
$ git log --boundary --graph --oneline <branch>...<branch>@{u}
* (branch) local commit 3
* local commit 2
* local commit 1
| * (origin/branch) remote commit 2
| * remote commit 1
|/
o last common commit
```

You may also have a nicer graph in some other views, like view commits where a branch forks off :

```
# will not show the history of 'master',
# but will show the commit on 'master' from which each branch starts
git log --graph --oneline --boundary ^master feature1 feature2 feature2
```