# Git: check if branch is strictly descendent of another branch

Tags: git, git-merge

I've seen a few questions about "how can I check whether a branch `X` has been rebased onto `Y`", but I haven't found one that has the particular flavor that I want.

I'd like to check whether `X` is a "simple branch descending from `Y`".  Strictly, only allow this pattern between `X` and `Y`, not the pattern between `Z` and `Y`:

[image]

In other words, if *every commit* in branch `X` has `Y` as an ancestor (or is equal to `Y` or is one of `Y`'s ancestors) -- not just whether the *tip* of `X` has `Y` as an ancestor.

This is desirable for helping people achieve a rebase-based merging pattern, where `X` is a feature branch and `Y` is the main development branch.  (If someone really knows what they're doing, and a non-strict-ff branch is what they really want, we can easily grant special dispensation and allow the merge.  But we want them to at least realize they're doing it, which keeps not happening.)

Note that this is *not* the same as "can be merged with `--ff-only`".  `git merge --ff-only` will happily update `Y` to point to `X` if `Y` is a descendant of `X`, even if some ancestors of `X` are neither descendants nor ancestors of `Y`.

I know I can loop through all the ancestors of `X` and check whether `Y` is an ancestor of each one (and stop when I get to `Y` itself, and make sure there's nothing with multiple parents), but I'm wondering if there's something better built-in to Git that I've missed.

**Addendum:**

As @TTT pointed out, another common scenario this would catch is someone messing up a rebase by `pull`ing before their `push`, instead of doing `push --force-with-lease`.  I created the following graphic for our internal "how to use Git" documentation, it would be great to have this check automated:

[image]

Comment: Out of interest, why do you need this?

Comment: The writeup says why, no?

Comment: I just want to point out that the rules you laid out allow for X to bring in new merge commits as long as both sides can reach Y. That might go against your desire to "achieve a rebase-based merging pattern".

Comment: Note that [LeGEC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75369041/184546) touches on the merge commits issue at the end.

Comment: Thanks @TTT - if I were doing my "loop through" solution I would probably abort if I find something with multiple parents (a merge commit), but in practice this doesn't seem to be much of an issue.  Branches tend to be either fully clean/rebased, unmergeable/outdated, or the work of someone using the "repeatedly merge mainline to feature branch" strategy.

Comment: @tymtam the idea is that it helps automatically check the policy we want in our repo, which is that people rebase before merges, to keep history clean.  For us, most of the time when people aren't doing this, it's because they didn't realize they were doing it, not that they have a philosophical difference about it.

Comment: @KenWilliams In one of my repos where we force a rebase+merge commit, we have a gated checkin that makes sure they aren't brining in any new merge commits, and if they are doing so intentionally, then they need to request a bypass to complete the PR. I'd add another possibility to your list- in my experience the most common scenario seems to be when someone  tries to do a regular push of their rebased branch instead of force push, and Git tells them they should pull first, and they wrongly do what Git suggests. ;)

Comment: @TTT absolutely!  Adding a picture that I put in our internal "how to use Git" documentation. =)

Comment: FWIW: if your intention is to have everyone work with a rebase workflow, you can have everyone set `git config pull.rebase true` in their local clone. At least a random `git pull` will not create new merge commits.

Comment: @LeGEC In the scenario where you should be force pushing, `pull.rebase=true` will still rebase your new commits onto your old ones. For a rebase workflow, my config preference is `pull.ff=only`, so that the merge portion of the pull will fail if it can't be fast-forwarded. (I recommend this config and advise my team that in the case where you really do want to either rebase or merge onto the upstream branch, you can do so explicitly.)

Comment: @TTT : 100% agree. I have actually stopped using `git pull` altogether, and use `git fetch` followed by the action I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to check whether all commits in `Y..X` are descendants of `Y` is to check the boundary of that range using `git log --boundary Y..X` or `git rev-list --boundary Y..X`.

Starting from this history :

```
$ git log --graph --oneline --all
* 036a9f9 (HEAD -> X) create d.txt
* cadd199 create c.txt
| * 0680934 (Z) Merge commit '22a23fe' into Z
|/| 
| * 22a23fe create b.txt
* | 8dec744 (Y) create a.txt
|/  
* 878ac8b first commit
```

You will get :

```
$ git log --oneline --boundary Y..X
036a9f9 (HEAD -> X) create d.txt
cadd199 create c.txt
- 8dec744 (Y) create a.txt   # <- one single boundary commit, pointing at Y

$ git log --oneline --boundary Y..Z
0680934 (Z) Merge commit '22a23fe' into Z
22a23fe create b.txt
- 8dec744 (Y) create a.txt   # <- two commits on the boundary
- 878ac8b first commit       # <-
```

A scriptable way to check if you are in this situation is :

```
# 'git rev-list' prints full hashes, boundary commits are prefixed with '-'
boundary=$(git rev-list --boundary Y..X | grep -e '^-')

want=$(git rev-parse Y)
want="-$want"

# the boundary should consist of "-<hash of Y>" only:
if [ "$boundary" = "$want" ]; then
   echo "all commits in X are descendants of Y"
fi
```

---

The above just checks that all commits come after `Y`. You could also be faced with the following situation :

```
* 036a9f9 (HEAD -> X) create d.txt
* 0680934 Merge 'origin/X' into X # <- someone created a merge commit in between
|\
| * cadd199 create c.txt
* | 22a23fe create b.txt
|/
* 8dec744 (Y) create a.txt
* 878ac8b first commit
```

and this would also get into the way of a rebase workflow.

If you also want to rule this out, use the `--merges` option of `git log` or `git rev-list` :

```
# git rev-list also has a --count option, which will output the count
# rather than the complete list of commits
merges=$(git rev-list --count --merges Y..X)
if [ "$merges" -eq 0 ]; then
   echo "all good, no merges between Y and X"
fi
```

---

The [documentation for `--boundary`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---boundary) does not give a good explanation of what a "boundary commit" is.

I would say [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42437590/what-is-a-git-boundary-commit) has a decent definition:

> A boundary commit is the commit that limits a revision range but does
> not belong to that range. For example the revision range HEAD~3..HEAD
> consists of 3 commits (HEAD~2, HEAD~1, and HEAD), and the commit
> HEAD~3 serves as a boundary commit for it.
>
> More formally, git processes a revision range by starting at the
> specified commit and getting at other commits through the parent
> links. It stops at commits that don't meet the selection criteria (and
> therefore should be excluded) - those are the boundary commits.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like this does the trick!  That successfully distinguishes between `X` and `Z` in the setup above.  I'll construct a CI/CD job that checks this.

Comment: updated the "merges" part, to make it clearer for future readers (and it also looks like this suits your needs)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for something like (in Bash)

```
[[ $(git merge-base X Y) = $(git rev-parse Y) ]] && echo yes || echo no
```

`git merge-base X Y` finds the *best* common ancestor and prints its full sha1 value. As to *best*, the [doc](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base#_description) says that

> One common ancestor is better than another common ancestor if the
> latter is an ancestor of the former. A common ancestor that does not
> have any better common ancestor is a best common ancestor.

In most cases, the best common ancestor is the nearest common commit of the 2 branches away from both heads.

`git rev-parse Y` prints the sha1 value of Y's head. If the best common ancestor is the same with Y's head, it meets that `every commit in branch X has Y as an ancestor (or is equal to Y or is one of Y's ancestors)`. In other words, the set of Y's commits is a subset of the set of X's commits.

But in practice, Y in the remote repository could be being updated by others and the local Y could get updated unintentionally. The test would say no even if X is really descendent of Y during the period after X has been created and before Y is updated.

Comment: That's pretty good! I was going down a different line, looking to see if the _last_ item listed in `git rev-list Z...Y~1` was the same as `git rev-parse Y` (which does work in this case). Something like `[[ $(git rev-list Z...Y~1 | tail -1) = $(git rev-parse Y) ]]`

Comment: to check for ancestry, there is a `--is-ancestor` option to `git merge-base` : `git merge-base --is-ancestor A D` (`A` is the would be ancestor, `D` the would be descendant). No output on stdout, you have to check the return value (or use a `if ...`, or a `... && something` or a `... || something`)

Comment: Thanks - however, this seems to report `yes` for both `Y->Z` and `Y->X` in my example sequence of commits, and I want it to be `no` for `Y->Z`.  The `merge-base` for all of `X Y`, `Y X`, `Z Y`, and `Y Z` all report the same hash as `git rev-parse Y`.

Comment: As for the `But in practice...` section - this should be fine, actually, because our Merge Request criteria will already reject a merge that becomes invalid due to a race condition.